# Implement Implicit Grant in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, oauth-2.0, gmail-addons

I want to implement Oauth2 Implicit Authorization Flow with Gmail Add-Ons. I have used  Apps Script's new StateTokenBuilder and /usercallback endpoint to handle the redirects. For the same, I have created the Authorization url on which user is redirected in another tab when he/she opted for authentication. After successful validation, there is the redirection to the below url.

https://script.google.com/macros/d/SCRIPT_ID/usercallback#access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&token_type=TOKEN_TYPE&expires_in=86399992

But Unfortunately the redirection will not happen as per expectation. But in redirection url if we use ? (.. /usercallback?access_token ..)  instead of # (.. /usercallback#access_token ..)  , the redirection works. Can you please explain where I am doing wrong.

Comment: Did you figured out the cause and solution to this issue ?
I'm also facing similar issue while implementing Implicit Grant O-Auth in Google App Script.
Please share your finding!! Thanks